# Existing react-native project doesn't contain "android" folder, what to do?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

My company gave me the source code for their mobile app written in react-native. It can be clearly seen that it was created using react-native cli. The "ios" folder exists there, but "android" folder is not included. I think previous developers deleted it at some point. I cannot run it on ios simulator because I don't have mac and I don't have iphone to use it with Vysor.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Eject and then link

```
react-native eject

react-native link
```